# zip two columns of a dataframe without changing the datatype

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dtype

The problem is simple. Here we have a dataframe with a specified datatype for columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
df.A = df.A.astype('int16')

#df
    A   B
0   1   3
1   2   4

#df.dtypes
A    int16
B    int64
dtype: object
```

Now I zip two columns `A` and `B` into a tuple:

```
df['C'] = list(zip(df.A, df.B))

    A   B   C
0   1   3   (1, 3)
1   2   4   (2, 4)
```

However, now the data type of values in column `C` are changed.

```
type(df.C[0][0])
#int
type(df.A[0])
#numpy.int16
```

How can I zip two columns and keep the datatype of each value inside the tuples, so that `type(df.C[0][0])` would be `int16` (same as `type(df.A[0])`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some type casting is happening when you refer as `df.A`, etc. See https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

> Return a copy of the array data as a (nested) Python list. Data items
> are converted to the nearest compatible builtin Python type, via the
> item function.

But this worked

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
>>> df.A = df.A.astype('int16')
>>> df['C'] = list(zip(df.A.values, df.B.values))
>>> df
   A  B       C
0  1  3  (1, 3)
1  2  4  (2, 4)
>>> type(df.C[0][0])
<class 'numpy.int16'>
>>> type(df.C[0][1])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Comment: Great point. I think in newer versions `.to_numpy()` is preferable to `.values`. The outcome is the same though. Thank you.